# Multinomial Logistic Regression vs. Logistic Regression Results in R

Tags: r, logistic, multinomial-distribution

I am running multinomial logistic regressions in R using the multinom function from the nnet package. Most of my variables are categorical, and oddly almost all of the variables come out significant. Not all, but almost all of them.

However, I know that few of these variables should be significant, if at all, and in fact when I tested with a regular logistic regression comparing just two levels of the dependent variable, I confirm that only a few variables (and only a few levels of those categorical variables) are significant.

The code for multinomial logit didn't flash any warnings. Are there any usual things I should check for troubleshooting?

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: Basically the code goes: glm1<-multinom(ctype~v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10,data=full_data)
summary(glm1)
coeftest(glm1)